# Serverless Framework - C# and Node.js in a single serverless.yaml

Tags: c#, node.js, serverless-framework

Is it possible to deploy both, a Node.js service and a C# service via a single serverless.yaml file? Any code examples would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

YES, assuming your cloud provider supports each language you specify. The Serverless Framework supports multiple languages (aka "multiple runtimes") in a single `serverless.yaml` config file. (Warning: I do not have C# experience, so I will use node+python as an example of multiple languages.)

Here is an example of multiple languages in a single `serverless.yaml` as you requested:

```
service: hellotime-app
provider:
  name: aws

functions:
  hello:
    runtime: python3.9
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: greet
    handler: web/handler.hello
    
  time:
    runtime: nodejs14.x
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: time
    handler: api/handler.timestamp
```

Reference: https://www.serverless.com/blog/building-mutliple-runtimes